# Select com 3 tabelas no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

[image: Tabela de Maquina]

[image: Tabela Equipamento]

[image: Tabela de Marca]

Eu preciso fazer um select na tabela maquina, porem quando executo meu comando

```
select maq.maqNip, equi.* from tblMaquina maq
join tblEquipamento equi on equi.equId = maq.maqTipoEqui;
```

sai o seguinte resultado[image: Resultado do select] e eu queria que aparecesse o nome da marca, o modelo e não somente o seu ID.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a relacionar essas três tabelas?

Comment: É só fazer mais um join com a tabela Marca através doz atributos Equipamento.Marca = Marca.ID, que parecem ter nomes dieferentes em suas tabelas reais.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta adicionar mais um `INNER JOIN` com a outra tabela de `Marca`:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tblMaquina maq
 INNER JOIN tblEquipamento equi 
    ON equi.equId = maq.maqTipoEqui;
 INNER JOIN tblMarca marca
    ON equi.marcaId = marca.marcaId;
```

**Observação:** Não se esqueça de alterar os nomes das tabelas e campos para ficarem iguais ao seu modelo. Fiz dessa forma de exemplo, pois não possuo os nomes dos seus campos.

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer assim:

```
select maq.maqNip, equi.*, marc.* from tblMaquina maq
inner join tblEquipamento equi on equi.equId = maq.maqTipoEqui
inner join tblMarca marc on marc.marcId = equi.equMarca
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente executar a seguinte query

```
select 
   maq.Nip, 
   equip.tipo, 
   marc.nome 
from 
   Maquina maq,
   Marca marc,
   Equipamento equip,
where
   maq.tipo = equip.id
and
   equip.marca = marc.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inclui também um `(NOLOCK)` para não alocar as tabelas em tempo de processamento

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tblMaquina (NOLOCK) maq
 INNER JOIN tblEquipamento (NOLOCK) equi 
    ON equi.equId = maq.maqTipoEqui;
 INNER JOIN tblMarca (NOLOCK) marca 
    ON equi.marcaId = marca.marcaId;
```

Comment: O `NOLOCK` irá fazer uma leitura suja, ou seja, se ele estiver numa transação que ainda não foi *"commitada"*, irá ler os dados antigos. Na pergunta ele não disse se precisa dessa situação.